# SDK/Library for rendering documents in Android

Tags: android, library

Is there a library for rendering office documents in my app?

- It should not be doing any conversion on the server side
- It should support at least these formats: `.xls(x)`, `.doc(x)`, `.ppt(x)`, `.odt`, `.odp`, and `.rtf`.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/TomTasche/OpenDocument.droid) help?